# How do you add a tag to a block in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

Ansible give this example:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-blocks

```
# myrole/tasks/main.yml
tasks:
- block:
  tags: ntp
```

and says "use a block and define the tags at that level" but then on this page:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html

they use:

```
 tasks:
   - name: Install, configure, and start Apache
     block:
       - name: Install httpd and memcached
         ansible.builtin.yum:
           name:
           - httpd
           - memcached
           state: present
```

If I try to "use a block and define the tags at that level", e.g. with:

```
 tasks:
   - name: Install, configure, and start Apache
     block:
     tag: broken
       - name: Install httpd and memcached
```

or (in desperation)

```
 tasks:
   - name: Install, configure, and start Apache
     block:
     - tag: broken
       - name: Install httpd and memcached
```

I get:

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key
```

What's the problem and how do you add a tag to that second example?

Comment: Fix the last two examples and the error message. It's `tags` not `tag`. The result is the misleading error `did not find expected key`. The real problem here is `mapping values are not allowed in this context`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm using a single tag not multiple tags.

Comment: The syntax is [tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tags) even for a single tag.

Answer (score 3):

- Put *tags* (and any other [block keyworkds](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#block)) **outside** the *block*, e.g. either **before** *block*

```yaml
 tasks:
   - name: Install, configure, and start Apache
     tags: not_broken
     block:
       - name: Install httpd and Memcached
         ...
```

, or **after** the end of the [*block*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#grouping-tasks-with-blocks)

```yaml
 tasks:
   - name: Install, configure, and start Apache
     block:
       - name: Install httpd and Memcached
         ...
     tags: not_broken
```

The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#grouping-tasks-with-blocks) says:

> *"All tasks in a block inherit directives applied at the block level."*

This is not true for *tags* **inside** a *block*. The code snippet below will fail with the message: *"mapping values are not allowed in this context"*

```yaml
- name: ntp tasks
  block:
  tags: ntp
    - name: Install ntp
      ...
```

The code snippet, where *tags* is **outside** the *block*, works as expected

```yaml
- name: ntp tasks
  tags: ntp
  block:
    - name: Install ntp
      ...
```

---

- **mapping values are not allowed in this context**

When you put *tags* **inside** the *block*, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Block
      block:
      tags: t1
        - name: Task
          debug:
            msg: Task 1
```

the play will fail with the error message:

```yaml
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

---

- **'tag' is not a valid attribute for a Block**

The correct [keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tags) is `tags` not `tag`, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Block
      tag: t1
      block:
        - name: Task
          debug:
            msg: Task 1
```

the play will fail with the error message:

```yaml
ERROR! 'tag' is not a valid attribute for a Block
```